# UI select form property "touched" not set on first interaction

Tags: validation, angular-ui-select, ng-messages

I'm trying to validate a **multiple ui-select** using **ng-messages** and **angular 1.3**. The `$touched` property is not being set on first interaction, i.e. click inside the select and then click outside. However, this works for textarea element.

Including the [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GckAl5YiWck0qAiSeKNB?p=preview). Could someone say what is wrong here? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's just a bug in 1.3 since 1.4.7 behaves how you'd expect. The ng-touched and ng-untouched classes on the input box are updating correctly, so that could be a workaround in some cases.